# Select component renders options horizontally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I'm using MaterialUI V5 and facing a issue with [Select component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/).

The input and its options are rendered wrong. Below are the codes and a screenshot. (I also posted my package.json).

[image]

```js
import { Grid, Typography, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Totals.module.scss';

export default function Totals() {
  const filterOptions = [
    { value: 0, label: 'This week' },
    { value: 1, label: 'This month' },
    { value: 2, label: 'This year' }
  ];

  const defaultFilterOption = filterOptions[0];

  const [filterOption, setFilterOption] = useState(defaultFilterOption.value);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFilterOption(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid className={classNames(styles.section, styles.totals)}>
        <Typography className={classNames(styles.title)}>Totals</Typography>
        <Grid>
          <Select
            value={filterOption.value}
            defaultValue={defaultFilterOption.value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="outlined"
          >
            {filterOptions.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem value={item.value} key={index} divider={true}>
                  <Typography>{item.label}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.11",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "jose": "^4.10.4",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0"
  }
}
```

Do anyone know what's wrong (I think there might be some modules that affect the component's default styles but not sure which ones do).

If you know anything about this issue or if you figured out where I'm wrong, please comment. Thanks very much.

I've tried looking for answers and some lead to a package with css conflicts: @mui/x-data-grid. However my project does not use that package.

Comment: I have tried to remove your css style classes and replicate your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-torvalds-1fwln0 and it is working fine. So may be there might be issue in the css styling that you use.

Comment: I really think my code is fine, even with all my css, however on my browser, the way the component renders is different from how it does on codesandbox. My browser (https://imgur.com/a/f7HGXlO) and on codesandbox (https://imgur.com/Jl5wV9T)